# How can I have my alias from a postfix server call a shell script that calls a python program?

Tags: python, shell, unix, alias, postfix-mta

When getting mail from `user@something.com`, my `/etc/aliases` file is setup like so:

```
user: |./tmp/delivery
```

My delivery file looks like this:

```
echo "@" >> tmp/log
---some text processing---
python addToStorage.py
```

However, when I get an email, it runs every command in the delivery file except for the `python` command. I tried adding `echo` statements around the `python` command but they did not print either. Essentially I want to receive email, do some word processing to it, and then call a `python` program from that same script.

I tried creating an intermediary script that simply calls the python program. When running that script on its own, it works fine. But trying to call it from the delivery file still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give an absolute path to your python file.
For example, try

```
python /path/to/addToStorage.py
```

Comment: I have the absolute path, python added to my path, as well as "#!/usr/bin/python" appended to the beginning of my python file, still not working.

Comment: you also need to add 
    /usr/bin/bash

to your shell. bash shell (or another shell if you're using it) will find python through its environment variables.